# Drag to move Image functionality Like Facebook Cover - React material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

I want to implement Reposition image(Cover photo) functionality exactly like the Facebook cover.
I have searched for any npm package but I am unable to find any package. I Have an original image URL and based on repositioning I wanted to save the new image in the s3 bucket. I do not find any article or package to start please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by react avatar image npm package but still you need to costumize it after that.
also you can use the link below

Comment: https://codepen.io/amirasalah/pen/abKrZm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).